# Transform between odom and base_link not made. ros2_controller Ackermann Steering Controller

Tags: ros2, odometry, tf, ros2-controllers, fixed-frame

I cannot set odom as a fixed frame inside RViz. It doesn't show up at all. My robot is fully functional and visible in both Gazebo. I don't get any warnings, errors or exceptions in the log. I'm using ROS2 Humble and Gazebo Fortress. I follow the code of the tricycle_drive_example from ign_ros2_control_demos (which publishes odom correctly if I run it on my laptop).

As intended by the controller, the topic /ackermann_steering_cotroller/odometry is published. Whenerver I try to visualize that topic with RViz, I get the following message:

```
[INFO] [1704543459.237610775] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'odom' at time 214,560 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
```

Running `ros2 run tf2_ros tf2_echo odom base_link`, gives this:

```
[INFO] [1704543792.043830485] [tf2_echo]: Waiting for transform odom ->  base_link: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
```

Also, my tf_tree looks like this:
[image]

The ros2_control tag inside my urdf:

```
<ros2_control name="IgnitionSystem" type="system">
    <hardware>
        <plugin>ign_ros2_control/IgnitionSystem</plugin>
    </hardware>
    <joint name="LEFT_HINGE_JOINT">
        <command_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="position"/>
    </joint>
    <joint name="RIGHT_HINGE_JOINT">
        <command_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="position"/>
    </joint>
    <joint name="LEFT_REAR_WHEEL_JOINT">
        <command_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="position"/>
    </joint>
    <joint name="RIGHT_REAR_WHEEL_JOINT">
        <command_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="position"/>
    </joint>
</ros2_control>
```

The configuration file for the controllers:

```
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 50

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

    ackermann_steering_controller:
      type: ackermann_steering_controller/AckermannSteeringController

joint_state_broadcaster:
  ros__parameters:
  extra_joints: ["RIGHT_FRONT_WHEEL_JOINT", "LEFT_FRONT_WHEEL_JOINT"]

ackermann_steering_controller:
  ros__parameters:

    reference_timeout: 2.0
    front_steering: true
    open_loop: false
    velocity_rolling_window_size: 10
    use_stamped_vel: false
    rear_wheels_names: [RIGHT_REAR_WHEEL_JOINT, LEFT_REAR_WHEEL_JOINT]
    front_wheels_names: [RIGHT_HINGE_JOINT, LEFT_HINGE_JOINT]
    odom_frame_id: odom
    base_frame_id: base_link
    enable_odom_tf: true
    odom_only_twist: false

    wheelbase: 0.324
    front_wheel_track: 0.387
    rear_wheel_track: 0.387
    front_wheels_radius: 0.055
    rear_wheels_radius: 0.055
```

In addition, here is what's on the log:

```
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] [INFO] [1704582360.211746217] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'ackermann_steering_controller'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] [INFO] [1704582360.222413325] [controller_manager]: Setting use_sim_time=True for ackermann_steering_controller to match controller manager (see ros2_control#325 for details)
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1704582360.288968173] [spawner_ackermann_steering_controller]: Loaded ackermann_steering_controller
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] [INFO] [1704582360.290052009] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'ackermann_steering_controller'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] [INFO] [1704582360.290166991] [ackermann_steering_controller]: ackermann odom configure successful
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] [INFO] [1704582360.295780665] [ackermann_steering_controller]: configure successful
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1704582360.569778822] [spawner_ackermann_steering_controller]: Configured and activated ackermann_steering_controller
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process has finished cleanly [pid 51038]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that tricycle_controller has a totally different codebase then the ackermann_steering_controller (which uses the same base as bicycle_steering_controller and tricycle_steering_controller, see [steering_controller_library](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_controllers/steering_controllers_library/doc/userdoc.html)): You cannot use the configuration directly.

Does [this note](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/issues/937#issuecomment-1875040977) here maybe fix your problem?