# Robot not moving in Rviz

Tags: gazebo, ros2, rviz, ros-humble, ros2-control

I am working on a 4 wheel ackemann steering robot. The robot is working fine and is moving as expected in Gazebo but it is not moving at all in rviz. Even its wheels are not moving (by looking at TF in rviz).

Both Map and Odom frame are not available to switch my "Fixed Frame" to.
I am using ros2 control and expecting Odom to be published by ros2_control but Odom frame is not available when trying to set fixed frame in rviz.

The full code with steps to reproduce is available at: https://github.com/nice-user1/ros2_acker/tree/master

Observe Rviz to notice the issue.

Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem and the answer posted here solved it for me:
[transform-between-odom-and-base-link-not-made-ros2-controller-ackermann-steering](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/107454/transform-between-odom-and-base-link-not-made-ros2-controller-ackermann-steerin/107474#107474)

Comment: After applying the changes (remapping to odom) transform from odom to chassi are published but transform from odom to wheels are not published and they appear white in rviz. Also the chassi itself is moving wierdly("yaw" means rolling in z axis) in rviz
I have provided the link of repo in the question with steps to reproduce error. You can try it yourself  if  you want.